# NSAnimationContext happening instantaneously

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation

I have a simple animation:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:15.0];
[tweetsView setFrame:finalRect];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

But it doesn't animate. The result is applied immediately. What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setFrame` call must go to view's animator proxy:

```
[[tweetsView animator] setFrame:finalRect];
```